# Vertical align with Created TTF Font

Tags: codenameone

On Android (in simulator or in IOS work fine) when used on a Label a created TTF Font (from a file), do not vertical align the icon with the font, the font are on top. When I use a native Font works fine.

My form code to test case, as you can see on ScreenShots, on IOS and Simulador the Valign is center on the Label and on the Picker, but on Android is align on Top, this success in all components

```
package test.kandy;

import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Font;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style;
import com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker;

public class ShaiForm extends Form {

    private Form previous;

    public ShaiForm() {

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        int fontSize = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(3);
        Font appFont = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Suisse Int'l", "Suisse Int'l.ttf" ).derive(fontSize, Font.STYLE_PLAIN);;

        FontImage fntImage = FontImage.createFixed("\uE161", FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont(), 0x0, 100, 100);

        Label labelCustomTTF =  new Label ("custom TTF");
        Style labelStyle = labelCustomTTF.getAllStyles();
        labelStyle.setFont(appFont);
        labelCustomTTF.setIcon(fntImage);

        Label labelNative =  new Label ("native Font");
        labelNative.setIcon(fntImage);

        Picker stringPickerCustom = new Picker();
        Style pickerStyle = stringPickerCustom.getAllStyles();
        pickerStyle.setFont(appFont);
        stringPickerCustom.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
        stringPickerCustom.setStrings("custom TTF Font");
        stringPickerCustom.setText("custom TTF Font");

        Picker stringPickerNative = new Picker();
        stringPickerNative.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
        stringPickerNative.setStrings("native Font");
        stringPickerNative.setText("native Font");

        add(labelCustomTTF);
        add(labelNative);       
        add(stringPickerCustom);
        add(stringPickerNative);

    }

    public void show() {
        previous = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        super.show();
    }

    public void goBack(){
        previous.showBack();
    }

}
```

[Font File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5t8rucqw6e4rbq/Suisse%20Int%27l.ttf?dl=0)

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eQFe.jpg)

[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vlfu.jpg)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqdSM.png)

Comment: I suggest filing and issue in the issue tracker: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new with this information.

Comment: Posted: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2798

Comment: The Bug is Fixed by the codename Team.

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2798